# how to add GET returns to WebApi tutorials for new classes

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, repository

I am trying to find the proper way to add more "GET" return statements to my first web api project using EF and repositories.  I've followed numerous examples and tutorials and they all show how to setup a web api, but now I'm trying to add to it.  Example being, if I have a second class, how do I GET all values from this new class?

So far I've followed the standard examples online and everything works fine.
What I have done so far is make a second controller, then add the method names to my IRepository, and the actual code to my Repository.cs.

I just want to make sure I am doing this the proper way.  Basically, should I just keep adding controllers for every class I want to return individually, then just keep making my repository longer and longer?  Is that the right way to do this?

FIRST CONTROLLER (BASED ON TUTORIALS)

```
    public class ClientController : ApiController
{
    private IRepository _repo;

    public ClientController(IRepository repo)
    {
        _repo = repo;
    }

    public IQueryable<Client> Get()
    {
        return _repo.GetAllClients();
    }

    public IQueryable<Client> Get(bool includeDetails)
    {
        IQueryable<Client> query;

        if (includeDetails)
        {
            query = _repo.GetAllClientsWithDetails();
        }
        else
        {
            query = _repo.GetAllClients();
        }

        return query;
    }

    public Client Get(int id)
    {
        return _repo.GetClient(id);
    }

}
```

IREPOSITORY

```
    public interface IRepository
{
    IQueryable<Client> GetAllClients();
    IQueryable<Client> GetAllClientsWithDetails();
    Client GetClient(int id);

    IQueryable<Trade> GetAllTrades();
    Trade GetTrade(int id);
}
```

REPOSITORY

```
    public class Repository : IRepository
{
    private xxxxV002Context db;        

    public Repository(xxxxV002Context db)
    {
        this.db = db;
    }

    //------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public IQueryable<Client> GetAllClients()
    {
        return db.Clients;
    }

    public IQueryable<Client> GetAllClientsWithDetails()
    {
        return db.Clients.Include("Mapping_ClientAccount");
    }

    public Client GetClient(int id)
    {            
        return db.Clients.Include("Mapping_ClientAccount.Account").FirstOrDefault(o => o.ClientID == id);
    }

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------

    public IQueryable<Trade> GetAllTrades()
    {
        return db.Trades;
    }

    public Trade GetTrade(int id)
    {
        return db.Trades.FirstOrDefault(x => x.TradeID == id);
    }

}
```

SECOND CONTROLLER (NEW)

```
    public class TradeController : ApiController
{
    private IRepository _repo;

    public TradeController(IRepository repo)
    {
        _repo = repo;
    }

    // GET api/<controller>
    public IQueryable<Trade> Get()
    {
        return _repo.GetAllTrades();
    }

    // GET api/<controller>/5
    public Trade Get(int id)
    {
        return _repo.GetTrade(id);
    }

    // POST api/<controller>
    public void Post([FromBody]string value)
    {
    }

    // PUT api/<controller>/5
    public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
    {
    }

    // DELETE api/<controller>/5
    public void Delete(int id)
    {
    }
}
```

---

Just as a test I added this to ClientController, and using Routes I returned data from a different class successfully.  So do I even need to have multiple controllers or can I just keep putting more methods in the one controller?  What is best practice?

```
    public class ClientController : ApiController
{
    private IRepository _repo;

    public ClientController(IRepository repo)
    {
        _repo = repo;
    }

    public IQueryable<Client> Get()
    {
        return _repo.GetAllClients();
    }

    public IQueryable<Client> Get(bool includeDetails)
    {
        IQueryable<Client> query;

        if (includeDetails)
        {
            query = _repo.GetAllClientsWithDetails();
        }
        else
        {
            query = _repo.GetAllClients();
        }

        return query;
    }

    public Client Get(int id)
    {
        return _repo.GetClient(id);
    }

    [Route("api/client/{customerId}/orders")]
    [HttpGet]
    public Trade GetOrdersByCustomer(int customerId)
    {
        xxxxContext db = new xxxxContext();
        var x1 = db.Trades.FirstOrDefault(x => x.TradeID == customerId) as xxxx.Models.Trade;
        return x1;
    }


}
```

Comment: Can you show some of your code so we can see what you have done so far?

Comment: yes, I added code above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would echo what @LoekD said, and I would add that it is a good idea to put http verb attributes on your methods, rather than just relying on convention.  It makes things clearer if your controllers get larger and it makes things more consistent.

For instance, on this method:

```
public IQueryable<Client> Get(bool includeDetails)
```

Make it:

```
[HttpGet]
public IQueryable<Client> Get(bool includeDetails)
```

It's not *necessary* but it will save you time in the future.

For your repository, it should really return only a specific type.  Based on your code above, you would want a repository for `Client` objects and another repository for `Trade` objects.

Other than that, I think you are on the right path.

Comment: thanks... I added the attribute tag [HTTPGET], and put my new sample at the end of my original post.  so should I even have multiple controllers or just keep making my original controller longer using routes?

Comment: one last question, what is the purpose for having multiple repositories?  wouldn't it be easier to just have one?

Comment: Your controllers should handle one type, just like your repositories.  It all comes down to the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle); your classes should do only one thing.  In your case, Clients and Trades.  It makes it easier to go back and read the code if you know that all of your code to handle retrieving Client data from the database is in the ClientRepository.

Comment: that makes sense, thanks for the background info and help!

Comment: one other thing, if I am making separate repositories for Client and Trades, do I make separate IRepositories also, or should they share the IRepository?

Comment: You can either use the same repository interface; just make a generic version of it, or you can make a separate interface for each repository.  Or you can make a separate interface for each repository and hav each of those interfaces implement a generic interface.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Routing feature to specify which GET operations your api supports, and which parameters it takes.

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2

For example, if you wanted to get a `User` by Name or by ID it could look like this:

```
[Route("users/{id:int}"]
public User GetUserById(int id) { ... }

[Route("users/{name}"]
public User GetUserByName(string name) { ... }
```

(The `Route` attributes are placed on your Actions)

Comment: thanks... using your tutorial and just as a test I added this to ClientController (example above), and using Routes I returned data from a different class successfully. So do I even need to have multiple controllers or can I just keep putting more methods in the one controller? What is best practice?